# pseudo input tags to obtain multiple different uses for input tags

Tags: css

On a page where input tags are used to generate css-only tabbed content, the goal is to simultaneously produce css-only modals...

```
<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked/>
<label for="tab1">#</label>
<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" />
<label for="tab2">∑</label>
<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3" />
<label for="tab3">µ</label>
```

as [an example](https://codepen.io/SMLMRKHLMS/pen/rVYRLQ).  However to accomplish this the styles for the `input` tags will end up conflicting between the initial purpose and this subsequent one.

Is there a way to define an alternate tag but with the same base properties of the input tag for the following set of definitions ?

```
input {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input:checked {
  height: 40px;
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 40px;
}
input:checked::after, input:checked:before {
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 100%;
}
input:checked::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

input:checked + label {
  color: #FFF;
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
}

input:checked ~ .modal {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.5s ease, height 0.5s ease 0.5s;
}
input:checked ~ .modal .content {
  color: #FFF;
  transition: color 0.5s ease 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: Add a class to each type of input (modal/non-modal) and write your rules based on that instead of `input`?

Comment: The suggestion that you use a class seems good, but if you really want to create your own tag you could look at custom elements https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements